# Is there a way to create localized synonyms at the package scope for constants in another package?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Scenario: `package_a` references a public constant in `package_b`

Existing code looks something like this:

```
PACKAGE package_a
IS
   PROCEDURE do_something
   IS
   BEGIN
      ...
      do_something_else(package_b.global_constant);
      ...
   END;
END package_a;
```

I want do do something like this:

```
PACKAGE package_a
IS
   SYNONYM global_constant FOR package_b.global_constant;

   PROCEDURE do_something
   IS
   BEGIN
      ...
      do_something_else(global_constant);
      ...
   END;
END package_a;
```

I do not want to create a local variable or constant that is set w/ the value from the other constant.
I do not want to create a public synonym.

I want it in the package private scope.

Comment: Being able to make local aliases for things like this would be a great addition to the PL/SQL language, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want it - and I don't see what advantage it gives except maybe a shorter name - you could use a private function to get a similar effect:

```
create package package_b is
    global_constant number := 42;
end package_b;
/

create package body package_b is
end package_b;
/

create package package_a is
    procedure do_something;
end package_a;
/

create package body package_a is
    /* private function */
    function global_constant return number is
    begin
        return package_b.global_constant;
    end global_constant;

    /* public procedure */
    procedure do_something is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Constant is: ' || global_constant);
    end do_something;
end package_a;
/

set serveroutput on
exec package_a.do_something;
```

Which outputs:

```
Constant is: 42
```

Because the function is declared in the package body only, it's private to the package, which I think meets your scope requirement.

Comment: This would definitely work, but I don't want the overhead of calling a function. Though I agree this would work and keep the code looking clean. To get around the function call though, I could add a compiler hint: PRAGMA INLINE(global_constant, 'YES');

Answer (score 0):

A `SYNONYM` is a SQL construct so, no, you can't declare a `SYNONYM` in PL/SQL with package scope.

What benefit would declaring a synonym in a package have over the options you reject such as a package variable in A that references the constant in B?

Comment: put "SYNONYM" in quotes. I want to do something like creating a synonym, but w/in the package private scope. Purpose: Cleanliness of code.

Comment: @scrappythenell - What is the cleanliness benefit of a synonym-like construct here over an identically scoped package variable that is assigned the value of package B's constant?  You can use a private function as Alex Poole suggests but I'm not clear whether that meets your criteria or not.  I'm not sure I see a cleanliness benefit to a synonym-like construct over a private variable or over a private function.

Comment: It would be cleaner in the definition and would help prevent other developers updating the value in one location, but not the original. it would also mean a cleaner memory space since it will still be pointing to the original value.